# How to downscale video using subprocess and then piping the data over to stdout and play using ffplay and save it as well

Tags: python, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, video-streaming

I am trying to use ffmpeg to downscale a video and pipe the stdout data to ffplay to play the new downsized video by piping it to ffplay on aws lambda.

This is the command I have so far, but for some reason adding a scale option is not working.

I am trying to run this command locally before I deploy it on python with subprocess command. I need the raw video to be able to save into database for streaming the data in realtime.

`%ffmpeg -i sample.mp4  -vf scale=240:-2 -f  mpegts -c:v copy -af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0 - | ffplay -`

adding the scale optioin for some reason is saving the video as the name scale=240:-2 which does not make sense.

Comment: It seems like you only want to view the video but not save the output. Or do you also want to save an output file?

Comment: for testing purposes I am trying to just view the video, but if saving it would be an option I would love to see how to do that as well, as when i remove the ```-``` option it just saves as an incompatible format.

Comment: Why not just use ffplay directly? `ffplay -vf scale=240:-2 -af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0 input.mp4`

Comment: This is actually needs to be piped to stdout in python and also to save the stdout in database as well, also have to save mpegts for proper output parsing within the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command makes it so that you can convert it in memory rather than saving the video to a local storage as mp4. You can remove the -movflags if you are formatting it as mpegts, but in the case of mp4 you need fragmented flag.

```
"ffmpeg " \
    "-i "+str(video_path)+" " \
    "-filter:v scale="+str(width)+":"+str(height)+" " \
    "-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov " \
    "-f mp4 " \
    "-af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0  " \
    "-"
```